# Mostrar tabla en HTML con Ajax y Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo el siguiente objeto JSON y quisiera mostrarlo en una tabla HTML:

```
 {  
    "data":[  
       {  
          "0":"328",
          "tr_id":"328",
          "1":"USE",
          "tr_oficina":"USE",
          "2":"4",
          "num_oficina":"4",
          "3":"1",
          "tr_turno":"1",
          "4":"2018-02-28 21:04:25",
          "tr_fecha":"2018-02-28 21:04:25",
          "5":"00:00:03",
          "tr_cronometro":"00:00:03",
          "6":"Alta de placas",
          "tr_tipo_tramite":"Alta de placas",
          "7":"c30010118 CFE CARLOS MODIF.jpg",
          "comprobante_domicilio":"c30010118 CFE CARLOS MODIF.jpg",
          "8":"Comprobante",
          "tipo_comp_dom":"Comprobante",
          "9":"",
          "identificacion":"",
          "10":"Comprobante",
          "tipo_identi":"Comprobante",
          "11":"",
          "factura_automovil":"",
          "12":"",
          "tipo_factura":"",
          "13":"",
          "poliza_seguro":"",
          "14":"",
          "tipo_poliza":"",
          "15":"",
          "carpeta":""
       }
    ]
  }
```

Así es como intento mostrar la tabla:

```
        success: function (response) {
            for (  i = 0 ; i < response; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                var nuevafila= "<tr><td>" +
                response[i].tr_oficina + "</td><td>" +
                response[i].num_oficina + "</td><td>" +
                response[i].tr_turno + "</td><td>" +
                response[i].tr_cronometro + "</td><td>" +
                response[i].tr_tipo_tramite + "</td></tr>"

                $("#body_tramites").append(nuevafila)
            }
        }
```

Comment: saludos la respuesta a esta pregunta la pudieras obtener con la información de este enlace, que es muy similar y lo conteste en la mañana https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145087/como-convertir-un-archivo-json-a-una-tabla-con-columnas-dinamicas-en-html/145111#145111

Comment: es mostrar toda la información de un JSON con ayuda de VueJS, axios y html

Comment: saludos si te sirve me avisas solo adáptalo a tus necesidades, como puedes notar no solo es mas simple leer el JSOn y recorrerlo si no que también es mas fácil mostrarlo dentro del HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ajax Completo:**

```
 var ajax = $.ajax({
        data:{},
        url:"lib/controladores/consulta_tramites.php",
        success: function (response) {
            for (  i = 0 ; i < response.data.length; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
                var nuevafila= "<tr><td>" +
                response.data[i].tr_oficina + "</td><td>" +
                response.data[i].num_oficina + "</td><td>" +
                response.data[i].tr_turno + "</td><td>" +
                response.data[i].tr_cronometro + "</td><td>" +
                response.data[i].tr_tipo_tramite + "</td></tr>"

                $("#body_tramites").append(nuevafila)
            }
        },
        error: function (response,status, error) {
            alert("error");
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando haces la llamada AJAX, en el `success` lees los datos del `response` e iteras sobre ellos:

```
    success: function (response) {
        for (  i = 0 ; i < response; i++){
            ...
```

Pero el problema es que `response` no es un array. Al menos no si el JSON que recibes tiene el formato que indicas:

```
{  
  "data":[  
    {  
      "0":"328",
      ...
```

El problema es que el array no está directamente en `response` sino en `data`. Por lo que deberías indicar que el array está en `data`. Además, en la cabecera del bucle, la condición de parada sería incorrecta porque no se estaría iterando todo el array (debes comparar con el `.length`).

Con esos cambios, el código del `success` se vería así y ya debería funcionar:

> Asumiendo que `response` se trata como un objeto y no como una cadena (en cuyo caso deberías hacer un `JSON.parse` al principio del `success`).

```
    success: function (response) {
        for (  i = 0 ; i < response.data.length; i++){ //cuenta la cantidad de registros
            var nuevafila= "<tr><td>" +
            response.data[i].tr_oficina + "</td><td>" +
            response.data[i].num_oficina + "</td><td>" +
            response.data[i].tr_turno + "</td><td>" +
            response.data[i].tr_cronometro + "</td><td>" +
            response.data[i].tr_tipo_tramite + "</td></tr>"

            $("#body_tramites").append(nuevafila)
        }
    }
```